# Force button clickable even if wrapped with IgnorePointer?

Tags: flutter

I am building a page where when user is performing an action all the click action should be voided, except certain button. The page will consist of quite a number of clickable action, so I wrapped them in `IgnorePointer`, however, there's also a button that I need to allow it no matter what.

Are there widget for this? Or there's no feature for this?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: It's just any widget that is wrapped with IgnorePointer but I want it still be clickable.